# Implementing Scikit Learn's FeatureHasher for High Cardinality Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data, feature-engineering

**Background:** I am working on a binary classification of health insurance claims.  The data I am working with has approximately 1 million rows and a mix of numeric features and categorical features (all of which are nominal discrete). The issue I am facing is that several of my categorical features have high cardinality with many values that are very uncommon or unique.  I have plotted 8 of my categorical features below which had the highest counts of unique factor levels:[image]

**Alternative to Dummy Variables:** I have been reading up on feature hashing and understand that this method is an alternative that can be used for a fast and space-efficient way of vectorizing features and is particularity suitable for categorical data with high cardinality. I plan to utilize Scikit Learn's FeatureHasher to perform feature hashing on my categorical features with more than 100 unique feature levels (I will create dummy variables for the remaining categorical features with less than 100 unique feature levels).  Before I implement this I have a few questions relating to feature hashing and how it relates to model performance in machine learning:

1. What is the primary advantage of using feature hashing as opposed to dummying only the most frequently occuring factor levels?  I assume there is less information loss with the feature hashing approach but need more clarification on what advantages hashing provides in machine learning algorithms when dealing with high cardinality.
2. I am interested in evaluating feature importance after evaluating a few separate classification models. Is there a way to evaluate hashed features in the context of how they relate to the original categorical levels? Is there a way to reverse hashes or does feature hashing inevitably lead to loss of model interpretability?

Sorry for the long post and questions. Any feedback/recommendations would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Feature hashing can support new categories during inference that were not seen in training.  With dummy encoding, you can only encode a fixed set of previously seen categories. If you encounter a category not seen in training, you're out of luck.
2. For feature importance, there are two canonical approaches.

   a) Train/evaluate your model with and without each feature to see its effect.  This can be computationally expensive.

   b) Train/evaluate your model with the feature and also with that feature permuted among all samples.

   With feature hashing, each feature expands to multiple columns so b) will be tricky and I haven't found any packages that do permutation importance of feature hashed columns.

   So, I think a) is probably your best bet, considering you only have 1 million rows.

Also, you'll probably get better answers on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for ML questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you!  I have one question in follow up.  When researching Scikit Learn's FeatureHasher I was looking at it as a method to reduce the dimension of the encoded table generated for each of my columns. How can I best determine the optimal n_features for each column in my dataset (I have some features with well over 1,000 levels) with the goal of obtaining an encoded table that does not exponentially increase the number of features being fed into my classification models?  I feel like this is somewhat of a balancing act.

Comment: You will probably be okay with log(N) dimensions, where N=number of categorical values. More so, if you are using the default `alternate_sign=True`

Comment: Would setting n_features = np.log(N) suffice for categorical features with low cardinality (let's say fewer than 10  levels) or would it be preferred to set n_features=N for those columns?